# Printing indexed terms using Lucene 7.4.0

Tags: java, lucene

I am at the moment attempting to print the Fields and terms from an index IO generated using Lucene 7.4.0, at the moment I have the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String indexDir = "C:/directory/to/index";
    index = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(indexDir));

    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);

    Fields fields = MultiFields.getFields(reader);

    for (String field : fields) {
        System.out.println(field);
        Terms terms = fields.terms(field);
        TermsEnum termsEnum = terms.iterator();

        //Term term = new Term(field);
        int count = 0;
        while (termsEnum.next() != null) {
            System.out.println(termsEnum.term().utf8ToString());
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
```

Currently this gives me a long list of jibberish in alphabetical order

```
3ñúä
3ñúæ
3ñúè
3ñúë
3ñúëµ
3ñúðéë
3ñúò
3ñúú
3ñû
3ñû5
```

I did attempt to use term.text() as well but although it would print the correct amount of lines, each entry would be blank. I feel like I'm close but am missing something small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I assumed I was over complicating the issue.

These weird values were caused because the actual field was more or less 'empty' (were blank but not NULL it seems).

As an answer to the question at hand I was going about this the wrong way trying to go from Fields to get the terms when a much easier way is to instead load the document and ask for the field I want from there

```
StringBuilder concat = new StringBuilder();

IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);

concat.append("Path , Parent \n" );
for( int i = 0; i <reader.maxDoc(); i++)  {
    Document doc = reader.document(i);

    String docPath = doc.get("path");
    String docParent = doc.get("Parent");

    concat.append(docPath + "," + docParent + "\n");

}
```

NOTE: I am using a StringBuilder as I was also exporting this data to a .csv